# How to echo from rows one by a number (without id)?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, mysqli

So i have a mysql table, and there are values inside it. I am echoing as much elements on my page, as much columns there is in the table. I am doing this with a looping, and i want to know how i can echo in all of these elements (what i am printing on the screen by the number of columns), a title what is stored in the table, every columns has this. How can i get by the number of the printed element, what title (or row) should i echo?
I am doing this with ids right now, but what if i delete a column? A number will be missing. So i need it without using ids. And sorry for my english, i am hungaryan
Code:

```
<?php 
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","***","***","***");
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `products`");
        for($i = 0; $i < $result->num_rows; $i++){
            $j = $i + 1;
            $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id` =" . $j);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $product = $row["name"];
            echo '
                <div class="demo-graphs mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-color--white mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col">
                    <img src="' . $row["imageurl"] . '" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
                    <h3 class="red-text">' .
                        $product 
                    . ' Alts</h3>
                    <a class=" mdl-navigation__link" href="edit.php?product=' . $product . '"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">edit</i> Edit</a>
                    <a class=" mdl-navigation__link" href="delete.php?product=' . $product . '"><i class="mdl-color-text--blue-grey-400 material-icons" role="presentation">delete</i> Delete</a>
                </div>
            ';
        }
?>
```

Comment: Show your code, show your table schema.

Comment: @MártonLederer For next time you're having issues with your code - You need to make sure it's in a separate paragraph, and then you select the code and click `ctrl+k` ([Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code))

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table2 where id=$allrowsandcolumns"
```

`$allrowsandcolumns` is an array of results from your database that contains col1, col2, col3, col4 from your first query. Visually, it looks like this:

```
$allrowsandcolumns =  array ( 
        "col1" => value1
        "col2" => value2
        "col3" => value3
        "col4" => value4
    )
```

I think we can agree that trying to put an array in a string won't work. Instead you likely want something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM table2 where id=" . $allrowsandcolumns["col1"]
```

Or whichever column is the id column matching with table2.

As far as echoing out all the rows... This looks to me like you're new to programming. But nesting is easily explained:

Right now you have this:

```
$options=mysql_query("SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table1");
while($allrowsandcolumns=mysql_fetch_array($options)) { 
    $options1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2 where id=$allrowsandcolumns"); 
} 
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($options1)) { 
    echo $rows['name'];
}
```

edited(without ids you could do something like this)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM table1");
$stmt->execute();
$array = [];
foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
{
    $array[] = $row['column'];
}
print_r($array);
```

results like

```
Array
(
    [0] => name1
    [1] => name2
    [2] => name3
    [3] => name4
    [4] => name5
)
```

Comment: But i want it without using ids